# Add a string of text into a html document using cmd/batch file

Tags: html, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I would like to add a string of text into a html document.
My website has an "update" part where you can see where they drove to. (Its a website for some bikers)
I would like to do it so my dad just need to open a bat file type a little information and then it would add the string to the html document.
Im currently using a "table" as the layout.
This is the code:

```
 <tr style="mso-yfti-irow:34">
    <td valign="top" style="width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-light:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
        <font size="4">DATE</font>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" style="width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
         <font size="4">LOCATION</font></td>
    <td valign="top" style="width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
        <font size="4">AMOUNT</font>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Current website

```
<html>
    <head>
        Some things here....
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            More things here
        </div>
        <table>
            the table/the place where new text should be added
        </table>
        A bit more
    </body>
 </html>
```

What I was thing was that I could make a bat file with this code

```
echo off
set /p Date="Date: "
set /p Location="Location: "
set /p Amount="Amount: "

(some command here to add it)

<tr style="mso-yfti-irow:34">
    <td valign="top" style="width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
    <font size="4">%Date%</font></td>
    <td valign="top" style="width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
    <font size="4">%Location%</font></td>
    <td valign="top" style="width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
    <font size="4">%Amount%</font></td>
</tr>

Exit
```

New text should always be added at the bottom of the table, however not the bottom of the html document

The line nr. will also always change

I hope I explained this well enough, if there was something you didn't understand then just write, then I'll try to clarify

Comment: Is this going to be hosted? You could use a bit of PHP to your advantage then.

Comment: Yes it its going to be hosted on a ftp server

Comment: Don't edit HTML files with batch files, use a language that natively supports HTML...

Comment: ascgipfl like what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you already have the bat script written to prompt your dad for the values.  So I will focus on how to insert those into your html page.

In your current html file, change the formatting of the end of your table, placing the last </tr> directly in front of the </table>

```
</tr></table>
```

in your bat file, replace

```
(some command here to add it)
<tr style="mso-yfti-irow:34">
   <td valign="top" style="width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
   <font size="4">%Date%</font></td>
   <td valign="top" style="width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
   <font size="4">%Location%</font></td>
   <td valign="top" style="width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm" height="5">
   <font size="4">%Amount%</font></td>
   </tr>
```

with this

```
powershell -command "(Get-Content Name_of_File.html) -replace '</tr></table>', '<tr style=&quot;mso-yfti-irow:34&quot;> <td valign=&quot;top&quot; style=&quot;width:180;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm&quot; height=&quot;5&quot;><font size=&quot;4&quot;>%Date%</font></td><td valign=&quot;top&quot; style=&quot;width:500;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm&quot; height=&quot;5&quot;><font size=&quot;4&quot;>%Location%</font></td><td valign=&quot;top&quot; style=&quot;width:523;padding-left:3.5pt; padding-right:3.5pt; padding-top:0cm; padding-bottom:0cm&quot; height=&quot;5&quot;><font size=&quot;4&quot;>%Amount%</font></td></tr></table>' | Set-Content Name_of_File.html"
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File replace_quot.ps1
```

This will execute a PowerShell search and replace command from within your batch script to find </tr></table> and replace it with the new row.  Each time your dad adds a new trip to the page, it will add the information to the bottom of the table.

The *powershell -command* lets batch know to execute everthing between the "double quotes" as powershell.  The get-content reads your html file.  So replace ***Name_of_File.html*** with the name of your HTML page.

The next part of the command performs a search and replace.  You must use &quot; instead " for powershell to read the entire line as a fluid set of actions.  It will write the HTML code and use your variables of %Date%, %Location% and %Amount% for the new values.

The file is then written back to the html page using *set-content*.  So make sure the ***Name_of_File.html*** is updated here as well with the name of your HTML page.

Save the following line in a different script named *replace_quot.ps1* and place this script in the same directory as your bat file.

```
(Get-Content Name_of_File.html) -replace '&quot;', '"' | set-content Name_of_File.html
```

This script will be called by your bat file to replace the &qout; with the actual " character in your html file.

Comment: It did work, kinda... </br>
So i got it to work however the .html file cant read &qout as a " therefor it makes the layout look weird. </br>
Would it be possible to make powershell go though the html document and get it to replace &quot with " </br>
Something like this </br>
    The script i have now
    powershell -command replace "&quot" """

Comment: Sorry that i looks so messy but i couldn't make another post... So i made a comment which looks a bit weird, hope you still understand it

Comment: I found a solution and will update the above text shortly

Comment: I have updated my answer to resolve the formatting issue.  Let me know how it works.